# Why is writing a high volume of log-entries with Log4J2 slower when using the Async logger

Tags: java, performance, asynchronous, logging, log4j2

I am currently seeking a way to get the best performance out of a logging utility using log4j2. The log4j.properties are

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.log-path = /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.immediateFlush = true 
appender.rolling.fileName = ${log-path}/jsonlogger.json
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${log-path}/%d{yyyyMMdd}_jsonlogger-%i.json

appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size= 1MB

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 4


logger.rolling.name = JSONLogger
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = FATAL
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = SYSTEM_OUT
```

Writing 100.000 log entries takes on my system about 4623ms.

If i create a log4j2.component.properties in my classpath with the following settings to make all loggers asynchronous.

```
# Make all loggers asynchronous 
Log4jContextSelector = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector

AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize = 262144
AsyncLogger.WaitStrategy = Timeout
AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy = CACHED
AsyncLogger.ExceptionHandler = default handler
```

Then it takes about 7891ms to write all 100.000 log entries.

According to the [log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#SysPropsAllAsync) an asynchronous logger should be able to log messages at 6 - 68 times the rate of a synchronous logger.

What is configured wrong ?

== Update 1 ==

In the mean time there have been some changes. The log4j.properties has been replaced by the log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration status="error" name="JSONLogger">

<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/jsonlogger.json"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/%d{yyyyMMdd}_jsonlogger-%i.json" 
                immediateFlush="false"> 
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout> 

        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
   <Async name="Async">
  <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="JSONLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="fatal">
         <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

The system property Log4jContextSelector has been removed from the log4j2.component.properties and now set using the maven shade plugin.

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <argLine>-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Running the following JUnit test gives more or less the same performance results now with or without the Log4jContextSelector system property set.

```
@Test
public void orderD_logDebugMessageXMLToJSONFileTest() {

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    String randomString = new BigInteger(130, random).toString();

    String xmlString = "<logMessage xmlns=\"http://reddipped.com/jsonlogger\">\n"
        + "  <Application>Application Name</Application>\n"
        + " <UserName>User Name</UserName>\n"
        + " <Identifier><FileID>F_" + randomString + "</FileID></Identifier>\n"
        + " <CorrelationID>" + randomString + "</CorrelationID>\n"
        + "</logMessage>";


    int messages = 100000;

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int x = 0; x < messages; x++) {
        // Write a debug entry
        SoaJSONLogger.getInstance().error(xmlString);
    }
    Long stop = System.nanoTime();

    Long msgsPerSecond = messages / TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds((stop - start));

    System.out.println("Messages/s : " + msgsPerSecond) ;
    System.out.println("Duration  : " + (stop - start) ) ;
    Assume.assumeTrue("Slow performance " + msgsPerSecond + " < 10000 ", msgsPerSecond >= 10000);

}
```

All results are around 
Messages/s : 10000
Duration  : 10630754228

== Update 2 ==

If i remove the disruptor jar from the classpath and the Log4jContextSelector system property the performance is still around 10000 messages/s.

When restoring the jar and system property and setting the attribute status of element Configuration in the log4j2.xml to TRACE the logger output to SYSTEM shows

```
2017-01-23 21:45:14,392 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=AsyncContext@232204a1, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@58695725] started OK.
2017-01-23 21:45:14,393 main DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED
2017-01-23 21:45:18,961 AsyncAppender-Async TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 2.0 milliseconds
2017-01-23 21:45:18,966 AsyncAppender-Async DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[/Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/jsonlogger.json to /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/20170123_jsonlogger-1.json, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2017-01-23 21:45:18,972 AsyncAppender-Async TRACE Renamed file /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/jsonlogger.json to /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/20170123_jsonlogger-1.json with Files.move
2017-01-23 21:45:21,987 AsyncAppender-Async TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2017-01-23 21:45:21,991 AsyncAppender-Async DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[/Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/jsonlogger.json to /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/20170123_jsonlogger-2.json, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2017-01-23 21:45:21,991 AsyncAppender-Async TRACE Renamed file /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/jsonlogger.json to /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles/20170123_jsonlogger-2.json with Files.move
```

Based on that i only can conclude that the logger is made asynchronous. Only the performance is the same.

== Update 3 ==

Replaced the RollingRandomAccessFile with the RandomAccessFile.

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/logfiles</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
    </Console>
    <RandomAccessFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/jsonlogger.json"> 

        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout> 

        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RandomAccessFile>
   <Async name="Async">
  <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="JSONLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
         <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console" />-->
    </Logger>
    <Root level="fatal">
         <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Create instance of SoaJSONLogger outside loop and added some 'warm-up' log events.

```
    int messages = 100000;

    SoaJSONLogger l = SoaJSONLogger.getInstance() ;
    l.error(xmlString);l.error(xmlString);l.error(xmlString);l.error(xmlString);l.error(xmlString);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int x = 0; x < messages; x++) {
        // Write a debug entry
        l.error(xmlString);
    }
    Long stop = System.nanoTime();
```

No change in performance;
Messages/s : 10000
Duration  : 10996023059

== Update 4 ==

Added by remco suggested test code

```
    // plain logger
    org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log4j2Logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("JSONLogger") ;
    log4j2Logger.error(xmlString);

    long startl = System.nanoTime();
    for (int x = 0; x < messages; x++) {
        // Write a debug entry
        log4j2Logger.error(xmlString);
    }
    Long stopl = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("startl : " + startl) ;
    System.out.println("stopl : " + stopl) ;

     Long msgsPerSecondl = (long) 0 ;
    if (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(stopl - startl) == 0) {
            msgsPerSecondl = (long) messages ;
    } else {
      msgsPerSecondl = messages / TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds((stopl - startl));

    }

    System.out.println("Messages/s : " + msgsPerSecondl) ;
    System.out.println("Duration  : " + (stopl - startl) ) ;


    //  plain logger end
```

Performance is now 100000 messages/s (10x previous performance)

Comment: How are you measuring this? Do the times you mention also include JVM startup and Log4j2 initialization time?

Comment: This was quite some time ago, but i measured this by saving the System.nanoTime(); juste before repeatedly writing the log entries and immediately after

Comment: Updated the question, see update 2. Performance seems now to be equal.

Comment: Can you try this: pull `SoaJSONLogger.getInstance()` outside the loop, and replace Rolling RandomAccessFileAppender with a plain RandomAccessFileAppender? Also log a few messages _before_ you start to measure to ensure Log4j2 is fully initialized before the test.

Comment: Also, instead of using `SoaJSONLogger`, what are the numbers with a plain Log4j2 Logger (please also place `LogManager.getLogger()` outside the loop and make sure to log some messages before starting to measure).

Comment: See Update 3 and 4. Will investigate differences further later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some logic in `SoaJSONLogger::error` that causes the performance to be 10x worse than when logging with a standard `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`. Perhaps that is a good place to investigate.

One more thing you can try is to configure with `AsyncLogger`:

```
<AsyncLogger name="JSONLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</AsyncLogger>
```

Comment: You were correct, the SoaJSONLogger can validate the received xml. When disabling the schema validation i am able to convert and write about 50000 xml messages/sec to json. 

When i remove the disruptor class from the classpath and do not set the system property Log4jContextSelector it takes about 277551293 ns to write 100k messages using the plain logger, after enabling the async logger it takes about 90074470 ns. About 3 times faster. Cheers Peter